# remove printscreen option is not available in ubuntu settings

Tags: system, settings, screenshot

I installed ubuntu to get rid of annoying messages from Windows update. Ubuntu is ten times worse than windows with this issue. Is there a way to make these work in the background without disturbing me?

However my problem is the really disturing sound of the printscreen key. The sound level is the highest level, totally disregarding any other program. I tried to find a way to disable this according to replies at Ubuntu forums. The only response that I can find, is disabeling it from the system settings. BUt the option is not there at all. Am I being totally blonde here as usually. Pleas help me remove this feature.

Comment: One question per post please, and do not rant but use neutral and objective language please.

Comment: Your question has been asked before. See this:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332415/85039

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way to silence `gnome-screenshot`: just rename the file `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga`. By default this is a symbolic link to `camera-shutter.oga`; instead of renaming it you may want to point it to a quieter or more pleasant sound, such as `dialog-information.oga`. Then logout and login again.